# How to filter records using two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like below:

**Table 1**

```
id  name    enrollno    subjectname batchname   groupname
1   abc       a1          s1          b1            g1
2   xyz       a2          s1          b2            g1
```

**Table 2**

```
sid subjectname batchname   groupname
1   s1          b1          g1
2   s2          b2          g1
```

I want to get records from `Table 1` which do not match any records in `TABLE 2` like below

```
name    groupname   batchname   subjectname
xyz     g1          b2           s1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM   table2 t2
                  WHERE  t2.subjectname = t1.subjectname
                         AND t2.batchname = t1.batchname
                         AND t2.groupname = t1.groupname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `LEFT JOIN` here:

```
SELECT t1.name,
       t1.groupname,
       t1.batchname,
       t1.subjectname
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.subjectname = t2.subjectname AND
       t1.batchname   = t2.batchname AND
       t1.groupname   = t2.groupname
WHERE t2.subjectname IS NULL
```

This might have a speed advantage if the join columns in `table2` had indices setup.